# Umbraco 7 render selected content in macro

Tags: umbraco7

how can i render a macro parameter "content picker" inside macro or display the html of the selected content?

Code:

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Macros.PartialViewMacroPage
@{  
    var carousel = Umbraco.Content(Model.MacroParameters["carouselContent"]);

}
@doctype
```

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: Are you wanting to render the ID, or get the actual content item in the Macro? If it's the actual content, try Umbraco.TypedContent instead of Umbraco.Content.

Comment: Yes. thanks for the help.
I finally got it

Answer (score 0):

Umbraco 7.5.5: Its best to make a special DocType with Template for it if you want it to behave as kind of Reusable Content Blocks. Then make a macro with a ContentPicker parameter and put this in it:

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Macros.PartialViewMacroPage
@{
    // returns id of content
    dynamic contentId = Model.MacroParameters["ContentPicker"].ToString();
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(contentId))
    {
        <div>@Umbraco.RenderTemplate(int.Parse(contentId))</div>
    }
}
```